# WinForms - Does WebBrowser control rely on installed Internet Explorer?

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a little application that includes the WebBrowser control.

Does HTML pages may look different on the client machine than from mine, depending to the version of Internet Explorer that he has installed?

And does the internet settings he have chosen within Internet Explorer will affect the WebBrowser as well?

Comment: What I wonder is now that Microsoft is looking to sunset IE, will WebBrowser controls stop working ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

The WebBrowser control *does* rely on IE installed on the client machine. However, by default it renders HTML pages the way IE 7 does, even if you or your client have a newer version if IE. This is in order to maximize compatibility. So unless you or your client have IE6/5.5, you are safe. If you want to target a newer version of IE, you need to set a registry key. See detailed info <strike>[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/cc817574.aspx)</strike> (at the far bottom), [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/IE9_Nags#What_IE_compatibility_mode_does_the_webbrowser_control_use.3F) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx).

Most, but not all IE Settings affect WebBrowser Control behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> Does WebBrowser control rely on installed Internet Explorer?

Yes

> Does HTML pages my look different on the client machine than from mine, depending to the version of Internet Explorer that he has installed?

Yes

> And does the internet settings he have chosen within Internet Explorer will affect the WebBrowser as well?

And yes again ;)

Comment: Thomas Levesque:Your answer is not accurate. Please see my own answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer (at the time of this writing) claims that WebBrowser relies on having IE installed on your machine, which is not entirely accurate today.  The image below shows it working on my personal device (Windows 11, no IE installed).
[image: WebBrowser working without IE installed]

For context, WebBrowser runs independently of IE 11 and should continue to work even though that browser is no longer supported.  Please see this [response from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/849067/how-will-ending-ie-support-affect-webbrowser-class) for details.  However, [there is an ongoing discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/pull/7582) to mark it as obsolete in .NET.